# What do we know about the Last Universal Common Ancestor (LUCA)?

Tags: evolution

All life on Earth (bacteria, archaea, eukarya) is thought to have evolved from a common ancestor, or last universal common ancestor (LUCA). What do we know about the characteristics of LUCA based upon extant life?

Comment: [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_universal_ancestor#Features) does a pretty fair job of summarizing the likely nature of the LUCA.

Comment: Seems rather broad at the moment. Perhaps one should constrain the question?

Answer (score 9):

Carl Woese has much to say on this subject, including:

> “The ancestor cannot have been a particular organism, a single
>   organismal lineage. It was communal, a loosely knit, diverse
>   conglomeration of primitive cells that evolved as a unit, and it
>   eventually developed to a stage where it broke into several distinct
>   communities, which in their turn become the three primary lines of
>   descent [bacteria, archaea and eukaryotes].”

There is a 2000 Scientific American article by W.F. Doolittle that discusses much of Woese's (and others') work understanding this question.

Also, see a couple of Woese articles [here](http://dx.crossref.org/10.1073/pnas.132266999) and [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.95.12.6854).